# How can I confirm an event when the player types a key word?

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I've a problem about typing confirmation.
I'm doing Virtual Spawner plugin.

If player has enough money and typing Y his spawner gonna upgrade to Lvl2.

My question is how can I do this Y or N confirmation? I thought with AsyncPlayerChatEvent. But this time every Y or N trigger Upgrading.

```
public static void jlvlup(Player player,int currentLevel) {
    String lvlup2= ChatColor.DARK_RED+"Do you confirm upgrade spawner to Level 2 for 5000000$ ?(Y/N) Write to chat.";
    if(currentLevel==1) {
         player.sendMessage(lvlup2);
         player.closeInventory(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter if you are waiting for player confirmation. You can do it in lot of way, but I suggest you to create a list, and put all players that need to confirm. For example:

```java
public static List<Player> waitingConfirmations = new ArrayList<>(); // create the list

public static void jlvlup(Player player,int currentLevel) {
    if(currentLevel == 1) {
         player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Do you confirm upgrade spawner to Level 2 for 5000000$ ? (Y/N) Write to chat.");
         player.closeInventory(); 
         waitingConfirmations.add(player); // here add to list
    }
}
```

Then, for the chat, do:

```java
if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && waitingConfirmations.contains(player)) { // check if in list
    // here pass to level 2
}
```

Note: `message` is the chat message. I didn't wrote full method as you didn't give it